# my guest can't get ip form my network dhcp?

Tags: ip, virtualbox, dhcp, bridge

i set below configuration for guest

**image description here**

[image]
but after set it and restart my guest, it can't get IP from my network DHCP!!!!
how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The network settings on virtualbox look good, as long as the interface is correct.

What is the guest os?

Have you tried the following on the vm?

if windows: run ipconfig /release then ipconfig /renew on cmd, or run diagnostics on the interface.  You can also try to disable and enable the interface. If nothing works, try setting up a static IP in the same subnet as the dhcp server and check if the server is reachable via ping (if it's not, troubleshoot your network).

if linux: dhclient [interface], also check if the interface is set to static or dhcp,  set the correct mode otherwise you will have to run dhclient again if you reboot or shutdown the vm

Comment: my host is windows 7

Comment: my host is windows 7, my ghest is windows server 2008

Comment: thanks for answer, i did any thing that you told me, but my NIC in my guest couldn't get ip from my dhcp, if i set static ip for guest, only my host can ping it and another system that exist my local network can't ping it